# jquery dialogue close without titlebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

[image: ugly one]I have this dialogue box that I would like to remove the title bar because simply it looks ugly, the only problem is that the title bar contains the close button which I need. To see an example of what I am talking about, you can see it here:

kitchenova.com

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("firstTime")==null){
        $( "body" ).prepend( "<div class='dialog-wrapper'></div>" );
        $("#dialog").show(); 
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        $("#dialog").dialog(
        {
            width:600,
            height:319,
            zIndex: 99999
        });

        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        localStorage.setItem("firstTime","done");
    }

    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function(){
        $('.dialog-wrapper').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

And yes I have looked at the dialog widget documentation and can't seem to make sense of it for I am not too familiar with jquery. Alternatively maybe you can help me have the dialog close by click outside of the dialog.This is what I want it to look like.

[image: good one]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a button to close the dialog and get it use the following code:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a close button to the initialization object:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    width:600,
    height:319,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

and instead of JavaScript to hide the titlebar you can just use css:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar { display:none; }
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9wZL/

Comment: how do I make the button? <button>close</button>

Comment: The button is added in the initialization object you see above: `..., buttons: {...` that block is what adds the button to the dialog.

Comment: I see, yeah I got it to work, but still not what I was looking for, in term of aesthetics, it is ugly looking. Thanks anyway. I added images to illustrate what I am trying to do.